# CakePHP: where/how to manage another system?

Tags: cakephp, directory

I have one more problem. I am working on migrating one big system (what is made in plain php/mysql) to CakePHP. In essence, there is two systems - one main system and second is placed in "/production". Booth have own UI, data is importing/exporting between DB and so on. In existing system there is no problem with that. But in CakePHP I don't know where to put this second system, to access it like it is now "/production". In webroot? or in plugins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"where to put this second system": probably the same places as the main system: controllers, models and views folders; if you want to migrate to CakePHP.

"to access it like it is now "/production": You can use prefix routing: http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing

Or if I misunderstood you, and you want to keep the code intact: it should be in the Vendor folder, but with that way, your 2 systems are not in control anymore.

The plugins are actually Cakephp apps that can be used in your app.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes I want that second system leave as is (too big, no time ti fully migrate). So I can put it in vendors dir - will be the best place for that? Can it then be accessable like "/system2" if I modify the routings (if needed)? What meant - "..but with that way, your 2 systems are not in control anymore."?

Comment: So you migrated the first one, but want to leave the second one intact? When you put it in vendor folder, it can only be called by your cake app, not directly accessible to users. So I think the best way is to put it in webroot folder, and config the routes or htaccess to remove the "webroot" part in the url.

Comment: Hi! I think webroot is best place for that second system. Can you please give me example of routes/.htaccess configuration for not showing in link "app/webroot"? Thanks

Comment: oh, I just test it, and it seems you don't have to config routes. Just copy the folder to webroot and check "/production"

Comment: Yes, it works, but it adds the "ugly" "/app/webroot/" prefix. What is the best way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: you can access it with "/production/", or if you need to fix that: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/grabanski/2008/06/17/add-trailing-slash-to-cakephp

Comment: Yes I can access it with "/production", but then site redirects to "/app/webroot/production". So the best way is managing .htaccess, right?

Comment: "/production/", with a slash at the end. You can find the fix in the link i posted above.